# Dependency Injection with inheritance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I'm using a pipeline build with MediatR. I'm adding a simple behavior aimed at validating queries and commands:

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<Result>
    where TResponse : Result
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators ?? Enumerable.Empty<IValidator<TRequest>>();
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
      (...)
    }
}
```

Currently most of my queries inherits from PaginatedQuery.

```
public abstract class PaginatedQuery : IQuery
{
    public int Offset { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Limit { get; set; } = 25;
}
```

Example:

```
public class GetCountriesQuery : PaginatedQuery
{
    public GetCountriesQuery(PaginatedInput input)
    {
        Limit = input.Limit;
        Offset = input.Offset;
    }
}
```

To make sure users don't send invalid Offset/Limit, I have built the following validator:

```
public class PaginatedQueryValidator : AbstractValidator<PaginatedQuery>
{
    public PaginatedQueryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Offset)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
            .WithMessage("Offset must be greater or equal to 0");
        RuleFor(p => p.Limit)
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .WithMessage("Limit must be greater than 0");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this validator is NOT injected into my ValidationBehavior even though TRequest is inheriting from PaginatedQuery.

> In the end, I would need to inject validators for the current TRequest AND also for all mother classes (ie: PaginatedQuery).

Is this something achievable?

Note: To inject validators, I scan for all types implementing IValidator<> (using Scrutor)

```
        services.Scan(x =>
            x.FromAssembliesOf(typeof(Startup))
                .AddClasses(c =>
                    c.AssignableToAny(typeof(IValidator<>)))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        );
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using AutoFac

Comment: Does AutoFac give you some way of inspecting the types that have been registered? Does `AbstractValidator<T>` implement `IValidator<T>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *Autofac* resolves a `ValidationBehavior<GetCountriesQuery, GetCountriesResponse>` you expect it  to resolve a `IValidator<GetCountriesQuery>` whereas only a `IValidator<PaginatedQuery>` is registered and `IValidator<PaginatedQuery>` is not assignable to `IValidator<GetCountriesQuery>`

You can try using the following C# statement

```
IValidator<GetCountriesQuery> i = (IValidator<PaginatedQuery>)null;
```

The C# compiler will give you this error message

> Error CS0266 : Cannot implicitly convert type `IValidator<PaginatedQuery>` to `IValidator<GetCountriesQuery>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In order to make it work, C#4 introduces covariance and contravariance for generic type parameter. It allows to cast `IValidator<Base>` to `IValidator<Derived>` or the opposite. See [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) on MSDN for more information.

In your case you need contravariance which can be declared by using the `in` keyword

```
public interface IValidator<in TRequest> { }
```

In order to make *Autofac* works with contravariant you have to register a the `ContravariantRegistrationSource` registration source :

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```

Comment: Great Cyril Thank you for your inputs. Didn't know how to allow Contravariance in Autofac!

Comment: to be more specific, in an asp.net core 2.0 with autofac, you just need to create the new method  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder). Then just add the line mentionned by Cyril and you are good to go!